# Include line nr in search result

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to figure out how to search a log file for "word" and also include on what line the "word" was found at.

Also if one can read from bottom to top?

Any ideas?

thanks!

```
    set seen_trigger2 ".foo"
    bind pub -|- $seen_trigger2 seen2:main


    proc number {list} {
    lmap item $list {list [incr number] $item}
    }

    proc seen2:main {nick uhost hand chan text} {

    set f [open /home/mydir/eggdrop/logs/mylog.txt]
    set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
    close $f

    set pattern $text

    set reverseNumberedLines [lreverse [number $lines]]


    foreach lineInfo [lsearch -all -inline -index 1 $lines $pattern] {
    lassign $lineInfo lineNumber lineContent
    putlog "$lineNumber : $lineContent"
    }
    }
```

...

Thank you  glenn jackman!

Thank you Donal Fellows!

Comment: `grep` from `fileutil` in tcllib seems what you're looking for: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.md#15

Comment: Read the file a line at a time, incrementing a counter with each line.

Comment: I also tried ::fileutil::grep, worked good. I think I'll try some more examples and see which I like the best. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from bottom to top is fairly expensive except in the degenerate case where all lines are exactly the same length. It's easier to read the whole lot in, split into lines, and reverse.

```
# Some features used aren't in 8.5 and before
package require Tcl 8.6

# Generates “line” numbers
proc number {list} {
    lmap item $list {list [incr number] $item}
}

# Classic get-all-the-lines code snippet
set f [open theFile.txt]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Number and reverse
set reverseNumberedLines [lreverse [number $lines]]

# Find the matching lines
foreach lineInfo [lsearch -all -inline -index 1 $lines $pattern] {
    lassign $lineInfo lineNumber lineContent
    puts "$lineNumber : $lineContent"
}
```

Note that I'm using the `-index 1` option, which basically applies `lindex $item 1` to each item in the list (the first sub-item is the line number, the second is the line text) before doing the search. Since we already have all the line numbers applied, we don't care about the actual indices we found them at, and can `-inline` the results.

Comment: Thank you Donal Fellows, always a pleasure! I couldn't wait so I tried it right away. I got this Tcl error [seen2:main]: element 1 missing from sublist "". I think i've done something wrong..

Comment: I'm using a trigger to set the "pattern". So ".foo happy" will save "happy" in $text. (I'm not sure how well you are into eggtcl. )

Comment: Element missing… I'm guessing that that probably means you didn't apply the line numbering (`number` procedure).